# Acomodar elementos en repeater

Tags: java, jsf

Estoy usando `<ui:repeat>` para mostrar los datos de una lista de un objeto llamado DescuentoPorPeso, el cual tiene 3 atributos :

- Un Objeto llamado TipoServicio
- Un entero llamado kilogramos
- Un double llamado costo

El código que uso para mostrarlo en la vista es el siguiente :

```
<ui:repeat value="#{descuentosCtrl.descuentosPorPeso}" var="descuento">
    <br/>

    #{descuento.tipoServicio.nombre} #{descuento.kilogramos} Kg :
    <p:inputText value="#{descuento.costo}" style="width: 200px;"/>

    <br/>
</ui:repeat>
```

La forma en la que termina mostrandose es la siguiente :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo la forma en la que quiero que se muestre es la siguiente :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no se me ocurre como hacerlo usando `<ui:repeat>`

¿Alguien tiene una idea de como lograrlo?

Answer (score 1):

Tendrías primero que quitar los valores repetidos de tu lista  `List <DescuentoPorPeso>listaLimpia` para eso puedes usar colecciones del tipo HashSet que quita duplicados [Revisar link hashSet](http://javainutil.blogspot.com/2013/05/java-eliminar-elementos-repetidos-en.html) en tu pagina como ejemplo podrias tener algo así:

```
<p:commandButton value="send" action="#{mainController.doProcess()}" update=":f1:aux"/>

<h:panelGroup id="aux">
<ui:repeat var="limpia" value="#{mainController.listaLimpia}" >
                #{limpia.tipoServicio}
                    <ui:repeat var="des" value="#{mainController.des}">
                        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{des.tipoServicio eq limpia.tipoServicio}" id="aux">
                            <p:inputText value="#{des.costo}"/>
                        </h:panelGroup>

                    </ui:repeat>
            <br/>

</ui:repeat>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Esto es mas una referencia que ud puede tomar espero que le sea de ayuda!!
Recuerde que el `.doProcess()` es el método que se encarga de quitar duplicados (listalimpia), en el repeat externo recorre la `List <DescuentoPorPeso> listalimpia` mientras que la interna toda la coleccion de `List <DescuentoPorPeso> tu_lista` para que al final solo realize una comparación en el `<h:panelGroup rendered="#{des.tipoServicio eq limpia.tipoServicio}"..../>`